# Create columns in data frame dependent on other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that has 4 columns. Of these 4 columns 2 columns are lower limit and upper limit values. For the remaining 2 columns I need to create corresponding 2 columns which will contain -1 if the value in the column is less than the lower limit, +1 if its higher than the upper limit and 0 if it lies in between. Below is my input(I want to compare the encode2_ columns with lcl and ucl).

[image: input]

I want the output(the columns with prefix encode3_) to be something like

[image]

I have some 744 such variables for which I need to create 744 corresponding variables. I have tried using apply but not to any result. Any help in this regard?

Comment: Any chance you share what you have tried?

Comment: You say: "if the value in the column is less than the lower limit, +1 if its higher than the upper limit and 0 if it lies in between" Where do I find your value?

Comment: @Al14 The values are in the lcl and ucl columns. lcl is the lower limit and ucl is the upper limit. The values that I want to compare are the ones starting with prefix encode2. I want to compare each of the encode2 columns to the corresponding lcl and ucl. The output of these are stored in encode3 columns in the second image

Comment: yes but you need a value that will be compared to lcl and ucl , where do I find it in `encode2_ columns`?

Comment: @Al14 I was updating my comment. please check again.

Comment: What does `encode3_ SALARY_0` is going to contain if the value in `encode2_ SALARY_0` is higher than lcl? Please check you question again!

Comment: @Al14 if its higher than lcl but less than lcl, the value of encode3_SALARY_0 is 0, if its higher than lcl, then the value is +1, if lower than lcl then -1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146869/discussion-between-al14-and-clock-slave).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case where the Excel-style wide format which is convenient for data entry and inspection is adverse to an efficient data processing. If there are many columns containing the same data it's often more efficient to reshape the data in SQL-style long format. For this, `dcast()` and `melt()` from the `data.table` package are used.

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
# coerce to data.table class, add a row number column,
# reshape from wide to long format all columns starting with Encode2_SALARY_
long <- melt(setDT(DT)[, rn := .I], measure.vars = patterns("Encode2_SALARY_"),
             value.name = "Encode2_SALARY")
# rename variable names
long[, variable := stringr::str_replace(variable, "Encode2_SALARY_", "")]
# show intermediate result
long[]
```

This is what we have got so far:

```
      lcl    ucl rn variable Encode2_SALARY
 1: 40168  46551  1        1          80984
 2: 57212 109839  2        1          42651
 3: 77285 114468  3        1          86248
 4: 86080 110821  4        1          94611
 5: 40168  46551  1        2          89193
 6: 57212 109839  2        2          59820
 7: 77285 114468  3        2         120393
 8: 86080 110821  4        2          82995
 9: 40168  46551  1      744          49292
10: 57212 109839  2      744           3823
11: 77285 114468  3      744         107498
12: 86080 110821  4      744          68502
```

Now, the new encodings are computed. Note that no nested `ifelse` are used but the facts that logical values can be coerced to integer (`TRUE` becomes 1, `FALSE` 0) and that `lcl` is less or equal than `ucl`.

```
long[, Encode3_SALARY := 1L - (Encode2_SALARY < lcl) - (Encode2_SALARY < ucl)]
long[]
```

which yields

```
      lcl    ucl rn variable Encode2_SALARY Encode3_SALARY
 1: 40168  46551  1        1          80984              1
 2: 57212 109839  2        1          42651             -1
 3: 77285 114468  3        1          86248              0
 4: 86080 110821  4        1          94611              0
 5: 40168  46551  1        2          89193              1
 6: 57212 109839  2        2          59820              0
 7: 77285 114468  3        2         120393              1
 8: 86080 110821  4        2          82995             -1
 9: 40168  46551  1      744          49292              1
10: 57212 109839  2      744           3823             -1
11: 77285 114468  3      744         107498              0
12: 86080 110821  4      744          68502             -1
```

Normally, other processing steps would follow in the long format. However, the OP has requested to get the result in wide format.

```
dcast(long, rn + lcl + ucl ~ variable, value.var = c("Encode2_SALARY", "Encode3_SALARY"))
```

returns:

```
   rn   lcl    ucl Encode2_SALARY_1 Encode2_SALARY_2 Encode2_SALARY_744 Encode3_SALARY_1
1:  1 40168  46551            80984            89193              49292                1
2:  2 57212 109839            42651            59820               3823               -1
3:  3 77285 114468            86248           120393             107498                0
4:  4 86080 110821            94611            82995              68502                0
   Encode3_SALARY_2 Encode3_SALARY_744
1:                1                  1
2:                0                 -1
3:                1                  0
4:               -1                 -1
```

The code should work with an arbitray number of rows and columns (sufficient RAM provided).

#### Data

As no reproducible data have been supplied with the question, the code below was used to create sample data:

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN verion 1.10.4 used

set.seed(1L)   ### This is important for reproducible sample data
n_rows <- 4L
sal_min <-  20000
sal_max <- 120000
DT <- data.table(lcl = runif(n_rows, sal_min, sal_max),
                 ucl = runif(n_rows, sal_min, sal_max))
# create column names
cols <- paste0("Encode2_SALARY_", c(1:2, 744L))
# create columns with random salaries
DT[, (cols) := lapply(cols, function(x) abs(rnorm(n_rows, 
                      mean(c(sal_min, sal_max)),
                      sd = (sal_max - sal_min)/3.0)))]
# round all columns to improve readability
DT[, (names(DT)) := lapply(.SD, round)]
# make sure that lcl <= ucl - after rounding !
DT[, `:=`(lcl = pmin(lcl, ucl), ucl = pmax(lcl, ucl))][]
DT[]
```

which yields

```
     lcl    ucl Encode2_SALARY_1 Encode2_SALARY_2 Encode2_SALARY_744
1: 40168  46551            80984            89193              49292
2: 57212 109839            42651            59820               3823
3: 77285 114468            86248           120393             107498
4: 86080 110821            94611            82995              68502
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Really appreciate the patience and effort. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

A reproducible code would be helpful but I think this is what you are looking for. if_else nested in if_else

```
df <- data.frame(lcl=c(10,10,10), ucl=c(100,100,100), 
                 Salary=c(2, 20, 200),
                 Salary33=c(3,30,300),
                 Salary77=c(4, 40, 400))

library(dplyr)


    fun <-function(x, y, z) {if_else(x<y,-1,
                         if_else(x>z, 1,0))}

    df %>% mutate_at(vars(Salary:Salary77), funs(Encode3=fun(., y=lcl, z=ucl)) )

     lcl ucl Salary Salary33 Salary77 Salary_Encode3 Salary33_Encode3 Salary77_Encode3
    1  10 100      2        3        4             -1               -1               -1
    2  10 100     20       30       40              0                0                0
    3  10 100    200      300      400              1                1                1
```

Comment: He is asking for two columns as output.

Comment: With different results?

Comment: It was not clear the question, he refers to lower limit

Comment: @MikolajMazurkiewicz lets say in place of salary my df has salary_1 unto salary_744 and I need to do the same for all of them. How do I scale this up to include that

Comment: if you want to run the function on multiple columns than you need to use mutate_at() and create new function. I edited my answer so you can see how it works now